# SpecFlow/MSBuild Codebehind Gen - Generate All task

Tags: visual-studio-2017, teamcity, specflow, msbuild-task

On a project I am working on, I am maintaining some Feature Tests written in SpecFlow.  Our team started using Visual Studio 2017 about a year ago, and we *finally* got around to doing some upkeep on our tests!

Our tests for the project I'm working on were originally written in SpecFlow 2.3.2, and were last updated in Visual Studio 2015.

The `SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator` is known to not work on VS 2017, so I spent the better part of yesterday changing our suite to use the `MSBuildSingleFileGenerator` instead as detailed in [this article in SpecFlow's official documentation](https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/)

**Problem:**
Locally, I can build my solution, including the Feature Test project just fine. 
 However, I keep getting the following error when I try to build the project on our build server:

```
[exec]  C:\CheckoutDirectory\My Awesome Project\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.2.3.2\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(45,5): 
error MSB4036: The "GenerateAll" task was not found. 
Check the following: 
  1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 
  2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 
  3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" directory. [C:\CheckoutDirectory\My Awesome Project\AwesomeProject.FeatureTest\AwesomeProject.FeatureTest.csproj]
```

I should point out that our team has **no** experience with writing MS Build tasks, as hitherto we haven't needed to; we use NAnt build scripts on TeamCity to manage our build work.  It's clear that error message *would* be helpful...if we knew **literally anything about it.**

Now, normally the correct answer would be: Google it.  I [did that](https://www.google.com/search?q=msbuild%20generate%20all%20task), and this specific error has no pertinent results.

Additionally, this is blocking my team, since we need our build to work.  I don't have the time to do the research and education necessary to properly understand how MS Build technology works.  That wil have to come later.

**Question:**
Bearing in mind that SpecFlow has broken our process, and our team's lack of knowledge about the MS Build system: I need to know how to get around the `"GenerateAll" task was not found` error.  What do I do to get around it?

**Secondary Question:**
I'm also open to lateral thinking.  Is there some way to hack either VS 2017 or SpecFlow to make the `SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator` "compatible" with each other?  The objective here is *NOT* to avoid making changes, but to control the changes.  I need a path towards transitioning from the old file generator to the MS build generation system.

**Additional Information:**
So, I did some digging, and I found a place where "GenerateAll" is being called in the `SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets` file:

```
<Target Name="UpdateFeatureFilesInProject"  
        DependsOnTargets="BeforeUpdateFeatureFilesInProject"  
        Inputs="@(SpecFlowFeatureFiles)" Outputs="@(SpecFlowFeatureFiles->'%(RelativeDir)\%(Filename).feature.cs')">
  <GenerateAll
    ShowTrace="$(ShowTrace)"

    BuildServerMode="$(BuildServerMode)"
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"

    ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
    ForceGeneration="$(ForceGeneration)"
    VerboseOutput="$(VerboseOutput)"
    DebugTask="$(SpecFlow_DebugMSBuildTask)" 
    >
    <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedFiles" ItemName="SpecFlowGeneratedFiles" />
  </GenerateAll>
</Target>
```

Because I've *confirmed* that this is being copied out to the build server, the situation is yet more mysterious.  It appears that the NuGet package is being pulled down faithfully.  Therefore, I can't figure out why my local copy is behaving differently than the copy on the build server.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to upgrade to SpecFlow 3 if possible. It uses MSBuild to generate the code-behind files.

Comment: Greg - That is part of what I would like to do.  However, the fact that making existing SpecFlow tests compatible with VS2017 has horribly broken our builds is kind of putting a damper on...well, a lot of things.  I need to contain this damage before I dare think about *upgrading*.

Comment: I'm not really sure what problems you are having. We've been using SpecFlow 2.4 with VS 2017 for a couple of years now with no problems. I've got builds running in Jenkins and Azure DevOps that are running SpecFlow tests. We use the MS Test testing framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you found this statement:

> The SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator is known to not work on VS 2017

The SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator is working in VS2015, VS2017 and VS2019. We see it as a legacy feature, but it's still there. Since some weeks it is disabled by default, but you can enable it in the options.

[image]

It works for SpecFlow >= 2.3.2 and 2.4. For SpecFlow 3 you have to use the MSBuild integration. There are some problems with older versions of SpecFlow, but with them it can also work. It depends on your setup.

---

About your MSBuild error:

The MSBuild Task for SpecFlow < 3.0 is in the specflow.exe. Is it on your build server? 
It is part of the `SpecFlow` NuGet packages. Normally you get this kind of error if MSBuild can't find the assembly where the task is.

For "debugging" problems with MSBuild, I can highly recommend to use the MSBuild Structured Log Viewer (http://msbuildlog.com/). With it, it makes it easy so see what is happening in your build.

We have an example for MSBuild Code- Behind- Generation with SpecFlow 2.3.2 here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/MSBuild/OldCSProj_SpecFlow232

You could compare your project with this example.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of SpecFlow.

Comment: Andreas - first, thanks for answering.  Ultimately, in order to just get stuff working so that my team isn't blocked, I wound up rolling back all changes, and removing the `MsBuildSingleFileGenerator` entirely.  It was faster to just not use it.  Because time is a factor - as noted in my question - the plan is to revisit upgrading SpecFlow versions and the file generator at a later date, when we've got the time to properly understand what's going on.

Comment: Additionally, where I got the "SpecFlow Single File Generator doesn't work in VS2017" thing from is https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/820 - my VS 2017 installation was throwing errors whenever I tried to force a regeneration of all feature file codebehind through Visual Studio.  The project itself hasn't changed, so it appeared to be a compatibility problem.

Comment: So, I accepted your answer.  It turns out that to get the test feature files to regenerate, I just had to turn on the legacy tool.  We still need to do our tech spike on the MsBuild upgrade, but at least now I'm not dead in the water.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Good to know that you are now unstucked @AndrewGray. When you are upgrading the next time and encounter problems, please open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow. We want to make the upgrades/updates as easy as possible. So if we missed something, we would like to know it so we can fix it.

Comment: Will do Andreas.  Thanks again.